# the limit of a convergent sequence

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

I don't get it. How do we exactly know that the sequence is decreasing and $lim a_n=0$?

Comment: The problem uses non-standard terminology. However, if the **series** $\sum a_n$ converges, where the $a_k$ are $\ge 0$, then $a_n\to 0$. In particular after a while $0\le a_n\le 1$ and therefore $0\le a_n^p\le a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't need to be decreasing. I suppose that what is meant is "convergent". Just the fact that $\sum a_n$ is convergent implies that $a_n \to 0$ because if $(S_n)$ denotes the sequence of partial sums, we have $a_n = S_n - S_{n-1}$, hence $\lim a_n = \lim(S_n - S_{n-1}) = 0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks!